# Chrome/Brave keeps signing out of websites on X11

Tags: x11, chrome

Sometimes, when I kill my browser, reboot, exit the browser normally, etc., basically whenever I restart my WM session *(I'm using StumpWM, which by itself has nothing to do with this issue)* the browser "forgets" that I was logged in, and that forces me log in back to every website, and some of them have OTP enabled, and that's utterly annoying and time wasting.

I think this may have to do something with the system keyring, or maybe something else. Where should I be digging?

**upd:** I found the [following thing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#xinitrc_method) on Arch wiki.

```
~/.xinitrc
eval $(/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh)
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

And did that. But I'm a bit skeptical. The hardest thing about it - it doesn't happen all the time. Only sometimes. I'm not sure what's causing it and I can't reproduce it. I'll watch my system for a few days, maybe this fixes it.

**Update**: That did not help. It happened again. I'm thinking, maybe there's some sort of grace period after which things get reset. I've also noticed  - git no longer recognizes GPG key and `pinentry` would ask to enter a password (which normally gets stored). My guess that this has something to do with the keyring?

**Update**: Switched to Firefox. Have been using it for a week. Haven't seen this issue so far.

Comment: Many of these "sign-ins" are remembered with browser cookies. Any reason to believe that those are disappearing?

Comment: Does the problem also occur with Chromium?

Comment: @K7AAY yes, Chrome/Brave/Chromium. I haven't tested other browsers though. I don't know how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: All three exhibit the same issue? Then that eliminates a user profile problem....

Comment: Did you confirm if your [user dir](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) is intact after you restart your session?

Answer (score 4):

Any browser keep your session active with the cookies... if the session is lost on restart/reboot that does mean that the cookies are cleared.

Cookies can be cleared automatically with:

- An extension that is meant to clear the cache/cookie like `cookie auto delete`
- Cookies settings on the chrome settings under the content settings (like shown on the capture bellow)
- Chrome store the cookies on the desktop keyring, if it is not accessible the cookies can not be loaded.

Quick solution without debugging:

- [Awsome cookie manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-cookie-manager/hcpidejphgpcgfnpiehkcckkkemgneif?hl=en) is meant to manage the browser cookie, you can as well **backup and restore** your cookies, doing so will restore any previously active session during the backup.

Solution:

- Check if your keyring (gnome/kde) is unlocked and accessible for Brave/Chrome also note that this system can be disable with `chrome --password-store=basic` the browser will use classic profile storage for it's cookies and saved passwords (saved datas will be accessibles on the profile folder so this may introduce a security weakness)
- Check if you have any application like bleachbit that would clear the cache/cookie.
- Try without your extensions, disable them temporarily start any site session, restart the browser and check if the session is still active.
- Check the related chrome settings under the content settings like the capture bellow.

[image]